# Does too many switch statements lower performance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, switch-statement, components

I'm learning React and am trying to make a component that displays an image dependent on props (game) passed through it. So far I'm using a switch statement that changes the source of the image, but I'm expecting to have a lot more cases than just 2 in the future. In all the switch examples I've seen online they only use like maybe 7 different cases. Is 50+ switch cases too much and will lower performance? I'm pretty new to coding and am wondering if this method is inefficient for lots of cases...

```
 <Pictures game=""/>
```

Pictures Component

```
import A from './images/game1.jpg'
import B from './images/game2.jpg'

function Pictures(props) {

  let source;

switch(props.game){

  case 'game_1':
    source = A;
    break;

  case 'game_2':
    source = B;
    break;
}
  return (
    <div>
        <img src={source} alt="First slide"/>
    </div>

  );
}

export default Pictures;
```

What I tried is technically working, but I'm not sure if it will make load times too long with 50+ cases.

Comment: Why not just create a lookup/index object instead of implementing 50+ switch cases?

Comment: just don't create 50+ switch cases. there are plenty way to work with it instead of switch case.

Comment: Will it hurt performance? No. Will it hurt readability and maintainability of the code? Yes. Make a lookup table/dictionary or something instead.